# Modeling question - twist/bend part of a mesh

Tags: modeling

Modeling question - twist/bend part of a mesh

Is there a way to twist/bend part of a mesh like this? I tried the Simple Deform modifier, but didn't really get a good result. Any suggestions?
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can try with curve modifier

Comment: But that's 100% do-able by the normal rotation tool

Comment: The easiest way probably would be to select the crossing edgeloop to be twisted, fill a non-manifold face there, rotate it around normal Z axis to create desired twisting and delete a face.

Answer (score 1):

Great method for shapes like that is shown here in the picture. Here is what you have to do:

- place 3 profile (can be more) meshes depending on what form you want. Profiles must have the same vertex count.
- join all the parts into 1 mesh.
- with profiles selected press W and then 'Bridge edge loops'.
- check 'Tools menu (T)' for more options if you need.
- apply subdivision modifier.

[image]

You can see the result in the second picture. This is similar. For your case you must adjust the placement of the profiles and then adjust the 2nd. profile to match the one you need. I think you will need 4 profiles to get an accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to try with curve modifiers, I tried an example setup for you to follow:

First, I created a similar arm shape, starting from a cube extruded and subdivided, and also a 3 vertex bezier curve object, straightened along the arm axis. Then I added a curve modifier to the above curve object, adjusted size and position. The subdiv modifier is to get a similar arm shape, with an edge loop.

[image]

Here you see the curve setup

[image]

Then in top view I starded moving one side curve vertex

[image]

which ended like this:

[image]

then I switched to right view

[image]

and moved the same vertex along Z to get the rough starting shape

[image]

Now, using the curve tilt tool on that same vertex

[image]

I twisted the mesh about 90 degrees

[image]

then inverted the selection, to select only the remaining 2 vertices of the curve, to adjust their tilt too:

[image]

Of course you can add more or less control points, and move, adjust, tilt them to get exactly the shape you need.

Hth